# How can I reference other rows in a Pandas dataframe apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to the following:

```
| Session | Leg | Talk Time Seconds | ... |
| ------- | --- | ----------------- | --- |
| 1       | 1   | 0                 | ... |
| 1       | 2   | 40                | ... |
| 2       | 1   | 35                | ... |
| 2       | 2   | 50                | ... |
| ...     | ... | ...               | ... |
```

If it is not the last leg in a particular session and Talk Time Seconds > 0 then the leg should be marked as having been transferred, as so:

```
| Session | Leg | Talk Time Seconds | Transfer | ... |
| ------- | --- | ----------------- | -------- | --- |
| 1       | 1   | 0                 | False    | ... |
| 1       | 2   | 40                | False    | ... |
| 2       | 1   | 35                | True     | ... |
| 2       | 2   | 50                | False    | ... |
| ...     | ... | ...               | ...      | ... |
```

I'm currently accomplishing this by breaking down the dataframe into a list of dataframes for each session. Using an *apply* and then concatenating the dataframes back together. This is taking a very long time to run and I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. My code is below:

```py
# get list of unique sessions
sessions = df['Session'].unique().tolist()

# list of dataframes for each session
session_dfs = [df[df['Session'] == session] for session in sessions]

# if it is not the last leg of the session and talk time is greater than 1 we can assume it is a transfer
for sdf in session_dfs:
    last_leg = sdf['Leg'].max()
    sdf['Transfer'] = sdf.apply(lambda row: row['Talk Time Seconds'] > 0 if row['Leg'] != last_leg else False, axis=1)

# join all the session dataframes into one dataframe
df = pd.concat(session_dfs)
```

EDIT:
When attempting the following suggestion:

```py
df['Transfer'] = (
    df
      .groupby("Session", as_index=True)
      .apply(lambda x: (x['Leg'] != x['Leg'].max()) & (x['Talk Time Seconds'].gt(0)))
      .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

I get this output:

```
>>> df[(df['Transfer']==1) & (df['Talk Time Seconds'] == 0)][['Session','Leg','Talk Time Seconds','Transfer']]

        Session         Leg   Talk Time Seconds    Transfer
11060   51000011288     1     0                    True
16167   51000011528     1     0                    True
15176   51000012182     1     0                    True
8468    51000012228     1     0                    True
2175    51000012585     2     0                    True
```

It looks like it is occurring on instances where talk time is 0 but it is the last leg of the call:

```
>>> df[df['Session'] == 51000012585][['Session','Leg','Talk Time Seconds','Transfer']]

        Session         Leg   Talk Time Seconds    Transfer
2175    51000012585     2     0                    True
3452    51000012585     1     0                    False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a mask to recognize if this is the last `Leg` of the current `Session` and one other to match the condition on `Talk Time Seconds`.

For the first part you can `group by` to take the maximum `Leg` of each `Session` and use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to check the criteria. For the second past a simple filter is enough.

The following code should satisfy your requirements

```
df["Transfer"] = (df["Leg"] != df["Session"].map(df.groupby("Session")["Leg"].max())) & (df["Talk Time Seconds"] > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solution provided the fastest results.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way.

First, create the data frame:

```
d = {'Session': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2},
 'Leg': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2},
 'TalkTimeSeconds': {0: 0, 1: 40, 2: 35, 3: 50}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Second, find the max leg number for each session; `.groupby().transform()` returns a series that's the same length as the original series.

```
df['max_leg'] = df.groupby('Session')['Leg'].transform('max')
```

Third, apply the logic to identify transfers (before last leg, time > 0):

```
df['Transfer'] = (df['Leg'] < df['max_leg']) & (df['TalkTimeSeconds'] > 0)
```

The result is shown below (I left max_leg) in, to show the result of the groupby/transform statement):

```
   Session  Leg  TalkTimeSeconds  max_leg  Transfer
0        1    1                0        2     False
1        1    2               40        2     False
2        2    1               35        2      True
3        2    2               50        2     False
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this works well, but I accepted a different answer as it timed faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df['Transfer'] = (df
                  .groupby("Session", as_index=True)
                  .apply(lambda x: (x['Leg'] != x['Leg'].max()) & (x['Talk Time Seconds'].gt(0)))
                  .reset_index(drop=True))

print(df)

   Session  Leg  Talk Time Seconds  Transfer
0        1    1                  0     False
1        1    2                 40     False
2        2    1                 35      True
3        2    2                 50     False
```

Comment: This does not appear to be yielding the correct results. I am getting rows where the Talk Time is 0 and the row is still marked as a Transfer.

Comment: @MosesWynn can you add that case to the data above so I can also check